# Issues with rpg stat system

Tags: batch-file

Im making an rpg game in batch, and here is the code for the stat system so far

```
:SPSPEND
CLS
Echo You have %SP% stat points to spend, every stat point used increases         that skill by 5.
Echo 1. Strength=%Strength%
Echo 2. Agility=%Agility%
Echo 3. Magic=%Magic%
Echo 4. Vitality=%MaxHP%
Echo 5. Defence=%Defence%
Echo 6. Archery=%Archery%
set /p choice=Choose what to put points into:
if %choice%=="1" Set /a Strength==%strength%+5
if %choice%=="2"
if %choice%=="3"
if %choice%=="4"
if %choice%=="5"
if %choice%=="6"
cls
set /a SP==%SP%-1
goto :rest
```

Not sure how to format soz. i need help with two things : how can i make it so that it doesnt close out and actually works, and how can i make a failsafe incase a person enters something other than what i already have set up.
Thanks in advance

Comment: You have a typo with the `SET` commands.  Only one equals symbol should be used.

Comment: I would use the `CHOICE` command if you are worried about validating user input.

Comment: Also use quotes on _both_ things that you're comparing. `if "%choice%"=="1"`, etc/

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you want.
I have tested it and am fairly certain it will work

```
:SPSPEND
CLS
if %SP% leq 0 goto end
Echo You have %SP% stat points to spend, every stat point used increases             that skill by 5.
Echo 1. Strength=%Strength%
Echo 2. Agility=%Agility%
Echo 3. Magic=%Magic%
Echo 4. Vitality=%MaxHP%
Echo 5. Defence=%Defence%
Echo 6. Archery=%Archery%
set /p choice=Choose what to put points into:
if "%choice%"=="1" Set /a Strength=%Strength%+5& set /a SP=%SP%-1& goto SPSPEND
if "%choice%"=="2" Set /a Agility=%Agility%+5& set /a SP=%SP%-1& goto SPSPEND
if "%choice%"=="3" Set /a Magic=%Magic%+5& set /a SP=%SP%-1& goto SPSPEND
if "%choice%"=="4" Set /a MaxHP=%MaxHP%+5& set /a SP=%SP%-1& goto SPSPEND
if "%choice%"=="5" Set /a Defence=%Defence%+5& set /a SP=%SP%-1& goto SPSPEND
if "%choice%"=="6" Set /a Archery=%Archery%+5& set /a SP=%SP%-1& goto SPSPEND
echo invalid choice
pause
goto SPSPEND
cls
:end
pause
goto :rest
```

Comment: instead of `Set /a Strength=%Strength%+5` you can use `set /a strength+=5` (same of course for the other variables)